# jQuery display all items of specific category when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really stuck on the following:
I need to filter a large list of items depending on the data attribute value, I have achieved doing this, 
the problem is when I want to display all of the items belonging to a specific selection. I tried adding multiple data attributes in the same element in html, but this is not allowed I found out:

Also used an if condition where I tried to separate the values with if value is not 'all' than ... but haven't had any success with this.
So this is where my last working code has ended up with.

html:

```
<select id="langOption" class="filterOptions">
    <option data-lang-option="all" value="all">All</option>
    <option data-lang-option="english" value="en">English</option>
    <option data-lang-option="spanish" value="sp">Spanish</option>
</select>

<select id="categoryOption" class="filterOptions">
    <option data-category-option="all" value="all">All</option>
    <option data-category-option="humour" value="hu">Humour</option>
    <option data-category-option="romance" value="ro">Romance</option>
</select>

<div class="displayBox" data-lang-option="english" data-category-option="humour">
    First Box English
</div>

<div class="displayBox" data-lang-option="spanish" data-category-option="humour">
    First Box Spanish
</div>

<div class="displayBox" data-lang-option="english" data-category-option="humour">
    Second Box English
</div>

<div class="displayBox" data-lang-option="spanish" data-category-option="romance">
    Second Box Spanish
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.filterOptions').change(function(){

    var theChosenLang = $('#langOption').find(':selected').attr('data-lang-option');

    var theChosenCat = $('#categoryOption').find(':selected').attr('data-category-option');


    $('.displayBox').css('display','none');

    $('.displayBox[data-lang-option="' + theChosenLang + '"][data-category-option="'+ theChosenCat +'"]').fadeIn();

});
```

Can someone help me out with this please, so that when all is selected all of the elements belonging to that selection and are also belonging to the other selection values.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a variable to store the selector's name, if the option that has been selected is **not all** then add it to the selector as a `data-attribute` filter. Otherwise, don't filter that option at all - meaning, show all.

Hope I understood you well and it would solve your problem.

```
    $('.filterOptions').change(function(){

    var theChosenLang = $('#langOption').find(':selected').attr('data-lang-option');

    var theChosenCat = $('#categoryOption').find(':selected').attr('data-category-option');


    $('.displayBox').css('display','none');
    var selector = '.displayBox';

    if(theChosenLang != "all"){
        selector += '[data-lang-option="'+ theChosenLang +'"]';
    } 
    if(theChosenCat != "all"){
        selector += '[data-category-option="'+ theChosenCat +'"]';
    }

    $(selector).fadeIn();

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L78846zz/)

Comment: thanks @Ofir Baruch, it worked just as it should. Very much appreciated.